# Visual studio does not identify the libraries

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I have been trying to code on VS lately and I have been facing the problems as shown in the picture that the C++ libraries are not detected/ identified.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMEQ4.png)

and if is m testing a code some times it shows that message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvmSY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by uninstalling all the related files of VS code and setup MinGW and vs code and save the path of the compiler again.